# SimpleXML get node value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Say I have this following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
    <parent>
        <child1>some value</child1>
        <child2>another value</child2>
    </parent>
</main>
```

I made a variable of the XML and now I want to get the values of child1, so I use SimpleXML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$this->xmlcode = (string) $xml->main->parent->child1;
```

But I get this message: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /x.php on line x

I also tried it with $xml->parent->child1, but no success.

Anyone??

Comment: *sigh* This must be one of the most frequent errors ever. When you load an XML document into a SimpleXmlElement, the root node is the SimpleXmlElement, e.g. `$xml = <main>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Gordon.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$this->xmlcode = (string) $xml->parent[0]->child1;
```

Comment: Problem solved for me by adding type (string) of (float) for example.

Answer (score 2):

A good example of using XPath with php for the SimpleXMLElement can be found here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php#95229

```
// Find the topmost element of the domDocument
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$child1 = $xpath->evaluate('/main/parent/child1')->item(0);
```

Comment: SimpleXml can do XPath queries. There is no need to convert to DOM to do so. The only advantage of using evaluate is when getting typed results, which your example clearly doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Variant for **xpath** (Also how to get content of node having dashes in name):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <main>
> <parent>
>     <child-1>some value</child-1>
>     <child-2>another value</child-2>
> </parent> </main>
> ```

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$node_value= (string)$xml->xpath('parent/child-1')[0];
```

result of $node_value:

> "some value"