# Get a particular xml tag from Curl Response(a rest api)

Tags: php, xml, api, rest, curl

Am getting a curl response like this,

```
<result>
<term>ve</term>
<rhymes>
mckie, mcnee, mcphee, mcphie, mcree, mcvea, moree, mt, musee, nabil, mckey, mcghie, mcghee, macphee, magee, marie, marquee, marquis, mc, mcbee, mccree, mcfee, mcgee, nestle, ot, partee, se
</rhymes>
</result>
```

i need to get the `<rhymes>` results in a string of array from the curl response.

Please help me to sort it out

### am putting the complete script here , please somebody check.....

```
$request =  'http://www.stands4.com/services/v2/rhymes.php'; 
    // The request parameters 
    $uid = '2634'; 
    $tokenid = 'kqjhvZfLrUQdrOCB'; 
     echo $term = "a"; 
     echo strlen($term);
    // urlencode and concatenate the POST arguments 
    $postargs = 'uid='.$uid.'&tokenid='.$tokenid.'&term='.$term;
// build request format
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs); 
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$response = curl_exec($session);
$rhymes_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

$rhymes = (string) $rhymes_xml->rhymes; //extract the string from the XML

$rhymes_array = explode(', ',$rhymes);
print_r($rhymes_array);
```

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593554/simplexml-get-node-value

Comment: Thanks Boy, But its not helping me out...can you brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple with [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
<?php
$curl_results = //get the xml with CURL...

$rhymes_xml = simplexml_load_string($curl_results); //turn it into an XML object

$rhymes = (string) $rhymes_xml->rhymes; //extract the string from the XML

$rhymes_array = explode(', ',$rhymes); //pop the result into an array
```

So `print_r($rhymes_array)` would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mckie
    [1] => mcnee
    [2] => mcphee
    [3] => mcphie
    [4] => mcree
    [5] => mcvea
    [6] => moree
    [7] => mt
    [8] => musee
    [9] => nabil
    [10] => mckey
    [11] => mcghie
    [12] => mcghee
    [13] => macphee
    [14] => magee
    [15] => marie
    [16] => marquee
    [17] => marquis
    [18] => mc
    [19] => mcbee
    [20] => mccree
    [21] => mcfee
    [22] => mcgee
    [23] => nestle
    [24] => ot
    [25] => partee
    [26] => se

)
```

**In response to your edit:**

The code looks a little messy... If you really need to use CURL (which can be helpful in some cases), it might look prettier if you make it a function:

```
  function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
  }

  //and also put the retrieving in a function:
  function getRhymes($term) {
    $url = 'http://www.stands4.com/services/v2/rhymes.php'; 
    $payload = array(
       'uid' => '2634',
       'tokenid' => 'kqjhvZfLrUQdrOCB',
       'term' => $term
    );

    $response = getUrl($url, 'post', $payload);

    $rhymes_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    $rhymes = (string) $rhymes_xml->rhymes; //extract the string from the XML
    return explode(', ',$rhymes);
  }

  // so now you can simply get the rhymes with:
  $rhymes = getRhymes('ve');
  echo "The following rhymes with 've': <br />" . implode(', ', $rhymes);
```

Here's working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qumUr6

CURL is very powerful, but most of the time you don't actually need its power, so you might want to use something more lightweight like [file_get_contents();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: but Quasdunk,    i am getting a array element with null value,when i put **$term = "aaaaaaaaa";** which is not available in the api term..

Comment: when i put **$term="asd"**....am getting **Array ( [0] => )** as result

Comment: Man I got it...Thanks for helping me out........Thanks a Lot @Quasdunk

Comment: Well, sure, if there is nothing that rhymes with a given term, the array will be empty, so you have to handle that case.

Comment: Handled it....Thanks Pro

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$str = '<result>
<term>ve</term>
<rhymes>
mckie, mcnee, mcphee, mcphie, mcree, mcvea, moree, mt, musee, nabil, mckey, mcghie, mcghee, macphee, magee, marie, marquee, marquis, mc, mcbee, mccree, mcfee, mcgee, nestle, ot, partee, se
</rhymes>
</result>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
echo $xml->rhymes;
```

Also, instead of simplexml_load_string and curl you can use simplexml_load_file('Here url you need')

Comment: am not getting the answers but anyway thanks for trying pal....

Comment: he need split the string to be array

Comment: Yes @Kannika ...absolutely right...

Comment: For splitting might use: explode(', ', $str) but better use $array_rhytmes = preg_split('/[, ]+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);